# Scope of variables replicated by multiprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to speed up training multiple models by using Python's `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async`. In order to save memory, I've converted my pandas dataframe into 32bit floats. I can see the pickle is ~2gb on disk. Once I've loaded the pickle into memory, I can see in task manager that python is using ~4-5gb memory.

I then create my tensorflow models in the main thread like so:

```
for i in range(n):
    self.estimators.append(DNNEstimator())

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    for i in range(n):
        # DNNEstimator is a wrapper over a keras neural network with scikit-learn
        # compatible interface (i.e., it has methods fit(x, y) and predict(x))
        self.results.append(pool.apply_async(self.estimators[i].fit, (x, y)))

    for i in range(n):
        self.results[i] = self.results[i].get()
```

My understanding of how `multiprocessing` works is that it pickles the data that needs to be processed, and run it in a new python process/instance. I noticed that each of the python processes was taking ~6gb of memory during training. I'm suspecting subprocesses are taking this much memory because it recreated all the variables in the main thread. So my question is, how much of the main thread's scope is recreated in each subprocess?